# How do I save a macro consisting of multiple search and replace into my .vimrc

Tags: vim, macros, replace, multiline

I have a macro that I use to replace special characters for its html entities. I would like to save it in my .vimrc.

According to [this](http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Macros), I should use let @r=' *macro_text_goes_here* '. The problem is that my macro is a series of search and replace, something like this:

```
:%s:á:\&aacute;:Ige
:%s:é:\&eacute;:Ige
:%s:í:\&iacute;:Ige
```

So, I've tried with ^V-enter, <enter>, <CR> using real line breaks, but it never works. On the other side, if I put the text on a register and then run the macro, it works as expected.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

adding this to .vimrc works for me

```
let @a=':%s/á/\&aacute;/g^M:%s/é/\&eacute;/g^M:%s/í/\&iacute;/g^M'
```

note that ^M is a special character entered using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd>, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>M</kbd>.

Comment: You're right, I had spaces between the ^M, and that's why it failed for me.

Comment: You can use double quotes and `\<C-m>` inside them if you do not want to have binary data inside your vimrc.

Comment: @smi +1 Thank you very much for Ctrl+V. It helped me a ton ^^

Answer (score 1):

Ok I found the solution, I had tried with **^M** before, but having some trailing spaces it didn't work, the proper syntax for the example on the question is:

```
let @r=':%s:á:\&aacute;:Ige^M:%s:é:\&eacute;:Ige^M:%s:í:\&iacute;:Ige^M'
```

Don't forget the last ^M, and that a vim restart is needed in order to reload the .vimrc.